# NaNin a linear time series regression

Tags: r, time-series

Say I have three time series:

```
y <- c(7, 8, 9, 2, 4, 5, 9, 4) 
x <- c(9, 3, 5, 2, 7, 1, 6, 1) and 
z <- c(NaN, NaN, NaN, 9, 10, 3, 5, 3)
```

Now I want to compute the following regression with R: `reg1 <- lm(y~x+z)` then `summary(reg1)`gives me the following output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x + z)

Residuals:
ALL 3 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   6.2414         NA      NA       NA
x             0.5172         NA      NA       NA
z            -0.5862         NA      NA       NA

Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
  (3 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:      1, Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 2 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA
```

So it seems, that the coefficients are estimated, but none of the t- values etc. My question here is, 1) why is there no error message and 2) how can I omit the NaNs from the regression, so R gives me t- values etc? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output actually answers this:

> ALL 3 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!

so there are no residual degrees of freedom to estimate the missing outputs. With this formula, at least 4 rows of non-missings will be needed in order to get estimates of the missing quantities.

Comment: thanks. Just added some more data points and then it worked! But a part of my problem still remains. The variable z actually looks like: z <- c(0, 0, 0, 9, 10, 3, 9, 4). Now I need to take the log of z: r <- log(z). But then if I want to run the regression: reg1 <- lm(y~x+r) I get the following message: Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  NA/NaN/Inf in 'x'. How can I omit the NaNs from my regression?

Comment: is it safe to just replace the 0 in my data frame with Na? If there is the value 0 in the variable z it means that at this point in time there hasnt been any observation.

Comment: just filter the zeros out of your data: `d <- data.frame(x,y,z); lm(log(z)~x+y,d,subset=z>0)`

Comment: Since these are time series data, you can use dynlm from the dynlm package: `dynlm(z ~ x + y)`, and it will eliminate missing observations automatically. In any event it's better to let R deal with the ts properties of your data.